# Wordpress website Cannot redeclare noindex

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error

My website https://www.greengo.uk/ stopped working and I just can't figure out why. The error message is:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare noindex() (previously declared in /var/sites/g/greengo.uk/public_html/wp-includes/general-template.php:3206) in /var/sites/g/greengo.uk/public_html/wp-includes/deprecated.php on line 4155

It looks like something happened after an update.

[general-template.php:3206](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2d1a.png)

[deprecated.php on line 4155](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EatRf.png)

I have deleted the .maintenance file but no luck. I have some important content on this website. Could you help me out how to make it work and recover it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same problem yesterday with one of the sites I've done for a client. I managed to restore the site by updating my local development version to Wordpress 5.7. and then manually replacing the general-template.php and deprecated.php on the server.

The site works now but unfortunately login screen still gives critical error.